# Symfony/Doctrine - Query to Set/Change the Value for a Field when Selecting an Entity

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

*[Usage: Doctrine 2.6, Symfony 2.7]*

Using Doctrine queryBuilder or straight DQL, how can I set a value for a field of an entity that is selected, or otherwise change or manipulate the value of a field that is returned BEFORE the postLoad event listener is called?

### Background

As a simplified description of my context, I have an entity `view` that can be associated with a ton of different "Content Type" entities, so it doesn't (can't) have a direct doctrine association. But I usually want that other entity to be loaded and attached to `view->content` property. So I have a postLoad listener that automatically checks what type of content it is, and loads it from the right entity if content hasn't been loaded already.

I usually want this to happen automatically, but if I get an array of views this lazy loading is too inefficient (too many database calls), so in those cases I want to fetch the content separately in a more efficient way after I get the results back (not in the postLoad listener one entity at a time). Which means I need to tell the listener to ignore it's usual automatic loading. I can do this easily if I am able to pre-populate that field with a `TRUE` value (so the listener thinks it's already loaded and doesn't try to fetch it automatically.

### Pseudo Idea for Solution

So what if when I create my query that fetches a list of `views` I make doctrine fill that field with a default value of `1`. In MySQL that is easy, just:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS `content` FROM `view`;
```

*NOTE: This unfortunately doesn't actually set the value of view.content, it just appends an alias called content...*

While `content` is a property in the `view` entity, it is not a persisted property, so there is no database field for that property. But I could make it persists (just as a placeholder). Let's say I do that, I still can't figure out how to manipulate the value that gets returned (always empty in the database) and pre-fill it with a `1` whenever I want to notify the postLoad Listener to ignore the auto loading.

Comment: Very good question! Unfortunately, this won't work:

SELECT a, CASE WHEN (a.option = 1) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'nooo' END as a.option FROM \Bundle\MyEntity a